# Theme parts path location dump

Tags: debug, include, get-template-part, paths, template-include

Few months back I was working on customizing theme that I was assigned to. I remember that I used some function or define something in the config or theme functions file and than it displayed debug information of exact path to every included file/partial, but I cannot remember what it was. I am googling for hours with no luck and I am running out of time (deadline).

When I set it it displayed path or url/uri to included files in currently opened file. Something like this but it also normally rendered the page. There was just this lines of debug information in it.

```
THEMEROOT/header.php
THEMEROOT/footer.php
and other partials
```

Now I have to customize very complex theme based on some kind of framework with hundreds of files and I am completely lost in it. I cannot find the location I need to change to achieve what I have to achieve.

I want to somehow dump this theme includes path but cannot remember how to do it and I running out of time. I've been googling for hours but did not find anything and it feels like a waste of valuable time.

Could someone point me at right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are some WP–specific solutions that track template files, for complicated projects pretty much the only reliable list is using [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) PHP function at the end of page load.

It would give you *everything*, including WP core, but filtering it down to theme is relatively easy.

Comment: Thank you, I've completely forget about that one. Filtering should not be a problem. Anyway could you please for the sake of learning mention those WP specific solutions?

Comment: @Joe you can check out [What The File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) plugin for example.